# Angular SVG text gets out of the view box

Tags: html, css, angular, svg, text

I am new to SVG and Im building some charts. I want to add some text on the top but it begins out of the view box. It seems like I could see the text if I scroll up but I am already on top of the page. It sounds stange but I hope it can be understood with the image:
[image]
I also attach the html code (as you can see the bottom part of the other texts is shown on the top, but just the bottom).

```
 <svg  [attr.viewBox]="DIMENSIONES" [attr.font-size]="100000" >

    <!-- Cuadricula (x=ancho_izq + margen_izq_centro; y=alto_indices)-->
    <rect x="10000" y="1500" [attr.width] = "ancho_cuadricula"  [attr.height] = "alto_cuadricula" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="350" />

    <!-- Todas las líneas -->
    <line *ngFor="let linea of lineasHorizontales"  [attr.x1]="linea.x1"  [attr.y1]="linea.y1" [attr.x2]="linea.x2"  [attr.y2]="linea.y2" stroke="black" stroke-width="50"/>

    <line *ngFor="let linea of lineasVerticales"  [attr.x1]="linea.x1"  [attr.y1]="linea.y1" [attr.x2]="linea.x2"  [attr.y2]="linea.y2" stroke="black" stroke-width="50"/>

    <!-- Índices (misma x que cuadrícula) -->
    <text x="10000" y="0" >0 1 2 3 4 </text>
    <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">I love SVG!</text>
    <text x="0" y="15" fill="red" transform="rotate(30 20,40)">I love SVG</text>

</svg>
```

DIMENSIONES is the string "0 0 106400 76500" and linea is just a model with x1, y1, x2 and y2.

I have been changing the font-size and stuff but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has arrived here with the same issue, it seems as the y property refers to the bottom of the text and not to the top.